# Npm install doesn't download dependency assets from Git LFS on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, git-lfs

## Background

I have a project that's split into several smaller projects with one main project that downloads the others as dependencies of the main project.

I'm using Gitlab to host my projects in private repositories, using deploy tokens to allow npm install to download them.

The dependencies are added to the main project using the following format in package.json:

```
git+https://name:token@gitlab.com/group/project.git
```

## Problem

On Windows when I do a git clone of my main project and run npm install, it does download all the assets using Git LFS, but on Ubuntu the assets aren't getting downloaded. If I check the contents of all the files tracked by Git LFS all I get is the information Git LFS placeholder. I'm using identical commands and software versions on Windows and Ubuntu, but with different results.

## I've tried:

- Updating to same versions of Node(10.16.0) and Npm(6.10.2) on both Windows and Ubuntu
- Updating to the latest versions of Node and Npm (I had to stick to version 10.x for Node because of some dependencies not working with 12.x)
- Adding a .lfsconfig file that points to the repository as described in the following issue: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11151
- Updating Git to the latest version (2.21 on Windows and 2.22 on Ubuntu)

## Current workaround

Currently I'm cloning the main project then manually cloning my dependencies into node_modules so that they're all proper git repositories so that I can then use git lfs pull in them. It works, but it's not how it should work, especially not since it's working as it should on Windows.

## Question

Why is npm install handling Git LFS differently for dependencies on Ubuntu vs Windows? How do I get npm install to work properly with Git LFS on dependencies, is there a settings somewhere I need to change to e.g. enforce Git LFS downloading?

Comment: Have you tried `yarn` instead of `npm`?

Comment: I assume git lfs was installed on Ubuntu and I would suggest testing this with a public repo also. This will at least corner out if it has something to do with private repos vs public repos

Comment: @TarunLalwani Just tried with `yarn` and it's the same result. The package is downloaded, but the LFS assets are not. I might try the private vs public test at some point, but partially because making it a public repo isn't an option and because it's pretty annoying to set up and I'm tired I'll hold off on it. Thanks for the advise though!

Comment: Not discussing public repo as an option, but more of debugging direction. Knowing that is important, so if you can do that it while be great

Comment: the [git lfs doc](https://git-lfs.github.com/) mentions: `'git lfs install' - You'll need to run this in your repository directory, once per repository.` Is git-lfs installed at all (system) and is git-lfs installed in the repo ?

Comment: If its a private repo then maybe its an authentication problem, so that on your ubuntu env a private key is missing and it can not access the files? can you access the private repo directly from your ubuntu via git?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Inside of your repository, run the following command and then commit the resulting .gitconfig and push:
`$ git config -f .gitconfig lfs.url https://gitlab.com/group/project.git/info/lfs`

Step 2. In the directory in which you want to npm install your project, run for example:

`$ npm install -S https://gitlab.com/group/project.git`